# Android get location via broadcast receiver and service

Tags: java, android

I am building a app which will track if they visited  a place on a specific  time and two achieve this  i am doing following

- Using `alarm manager` to start a `BroadcastReceiver`
- In BroadcastReceiver i am starting a service which will get user last known location

I don't know that this is the best approach to accomplish this, it works sometime and sometime  app just crashes. below is my code it would be great if anyone show me what i am doing wrong.

**MainActivty**

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentHourIn24Format = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int currentMinuteIn24Format = rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

       // Toast.makeText(this, "Time is:"+currentMinuteIn24Format, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, currentHourIn24Format);
        cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, currentMinuteIn24Format+1);
        cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, currentHourIn24Format);
        cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, currentMinuteIn24Format+2);
        cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

         // Test if the times are in the past, if they are add one day
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        if(now.after(cal1))
            cal1.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
        if(now.after(cal2))
            cal2.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);

        // Create two different PendingIntents, they MUST have different requestCodes
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourBroadCastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent morningAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        PendingIntent eveningAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);

        // Start both alarms, set to repeat once every day
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, morningAlarm);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, eveningAlarm);
```

**BroadCastReceiver**

```
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent i = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
        context.startService(i);

    }
```

**LocationService**

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public LocationService() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       // Toast.makeText(this, "Service started....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
       // mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LocationService.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            return;
        }
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            String location  = mLastLocation.getLatitude()+","+mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(this, location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }
}
```